# Android SQLite update query showing error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a following table:

```
sdb.execSQL("create table if not exists userprofile (id integer primary key, profilename text, user text);");
```

I want to update profilename field in Android SQLite.

So I used the following code:

```
ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
cv.put("user",et4.getText().toString());
String admin="user1";
sdb.update("userprofile", cv, "profilename = " + admin, null);
```

The table have profilename value as user1. But when I execute this I am getting

```
03-14 09:12:55.851: E/SQLiteLog(26616): (1) no such column: user1
```

Please help me to resolve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check values in content value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
sdb.update("userprofile", cv, "profilename = ?", new String[] {"user1"});
```

I recommend this approach. Usage of placeholders solve problems like this. Your approach doesn't work because you are missing single quotes.

Comment: does it work like `insert into` or just update specific field?

Comment: @100kg this will update userprofile with profileName = 'user1'

Comment: can I somehow use ContentValues to `insert into` without writting `insert into` ?

Comment: @100kg for sure you can as couple of values cv.put("column_name", "new value"); insert into clause is db.insert() method.

Comment: @100kg of you want to write full query as "insert into Table values(?,?)" you need to use SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(queryString); stmnt.bindString(1, "val1"); stmnt.bindString(2, "val2"); stmnt.executeInsert();

Answer (score 1):

It should be -

```
ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
cv.put("user",et4.getText().toString());
String admin="user1";
sdb.update("userprofile", cv, "profilename = '" + admin +"'", null);
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: your approach too is working fine.Thank you.So +1 to you also